# Biblatex creates big linebreaks if Reference Entry fills whole line

Tags: biblatex, line-breaking, bibentry

I use biblatex to cite my references. Printing my bibliography works almost as expected. If the entry's last character (in my case a dot) is at the end of a line, a big line break occurs. So a big gap is between the entry and the next one.

Here is a screenshot. The spacing between [91] and [92] is bigger, due to [91] text is filling the whole line.

[image: Screenshot]

I assume the big break should separate entries visually.

### Any ideas where to remove this extra big linebreak?

UPDATE: I found this snippet in my class template:

```
% Autoref
\addto\extrasngerman{%
     \def\equationautorefname~#1\null{(#1)\null} %Reference to equations in parentheses
}%
```

If delete these lines, the problem is gone. Does this make sense?? Seems i need an alternative to display referenced equations in parentheses like: (1).

Comment: I would guess you have a spurious space token that ends as a line on its own but as you have shown no code impossible to guess where or suggest what to change. Please always try to give a small complete example document that shows the problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is a spurious space in the `\extrasngerman` call

```
\documentclass[british,ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}

\addto\extrasngerman{%
     \def\equationautorefname~#1\null{(#1)\null} %Reference to equations in parentheses
}%

\begin{document}
A\selectlanguage{ngerman}B\selectlanguage{british}C
\end{document}
```

[image: A BC]

The space before the `%` might cause unwanted space when you switch languages in some contexts.

You could try

```
\documentclass[british,ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}

\addto\extrasngerman{%
  \def\equationautorefname~#1\null{(#1)\null}%
}

\begin{document}
A\selectlanguage{ngerman}B\selectlanguage{british}C
\end{document}
```

instead, which should not introduce spurious spaces when the language is switched.

[image: ABC]

Whether this helps resolve the issue in your document is hard to tell from afar, but this is all we got at the moment.